# Webpack source-map does not resolve sass imports

Tags: css, webpack, sass, source-maps

I have webpack configured to transpile scss -> css, but sourcemap generated by webpack does not resolve scss `@import`s.

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['./src/main.scss'],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: outputPath
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { // sass / scss loader for webpack
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                            import: true,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                        }
                    },
                    'sass-loader'
                ])
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ // define where to save the file
            filename: 'css/[name].bundle.css',
            allChunks: true,
        })
    ]
};
```

main.scss:

```
@import 'foo';
```

_foo.scss:

```
h1 { color: red; }
```

However, in Chrome dev tools, I see a reference to `main.scss` where I expect reference to `_foo.scss` - see the screenshot below:

[image: _foo.scss not resolved]

Compiled demo: http://store.amniverse.net/webpacktest/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `sass-loader` there, switch it with:

```
{
   loader: 'sass-loader',
   options: {
     sourceMap: true
   }
}
```

And that would work.

Comment: Just noted that there is currently a bug https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/351 so that it cannot be used with compressed output, so you have to disable sass source mapping for production build. But it is still much useful! :)

Comment: @amik Indeed, though you probably don't want to have source maps in production since it's more code and builds up in size.

Answer (score 5):

You should not use extractTextPlugin when you are in dev mode. 
Please make extra configs for dev and production mode. In production the use of extractTextPlugin is fine but in dev mode it is not necessary and can lead to other features not working. So instead use the style-loader.

Also - I am not sure if that fixes your problem - try to use importLoaders prop on the css loader. Look here for more info:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#importloaders

```
const path = require('path');

const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['./src/main.scss'],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
        path: outputPath
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { // sass / scss loader for webpack
                test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
                loader: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                          sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false,
                            import: true,
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true,
                            importLoaders: 1,
                        }
                    },
                    {
                       loader: 'sass-loader',
                       options: {
                         sourceMap: true
                       }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with `ExtractTextPlugin` in dev mode, and what @Omri Aharon posted is correct. However, what **you should consider** is having source-map enabled only in dev mode.

To build webpack using its default production settings (which uglifies and applies OccurrenceOrderPlugin plugin by default in webpack 2.0+), run the command `webpack -p`, and then in your `webpack.config.js`, you can determine if you're in dev mode or not by doing:

```
const DEBUG = !process.argv.includes('-p');
```

Add the function

```
function cssConfig(modules) {
    return {
        sourceMap: DEBUG,
        modules,
        localIdentName: DEBUG ? '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:3]' : '[hash:base64:4]',
        minimize: !DEBUG
    };
}
```

in your `webpack.config.js`, making your scss loader appear as so:

```
            test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: 'style-loader',
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: cssConfig(true)
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: DEBUG }
                    }
                ]
            })
        },
```

and my plugins section has

`new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css?[contenthash]'),`